# DNN custom skin and css deployment

Tags: dotnetnuke, skins

I am new to this and trying to figure this out. I have created a internal.ascx page and a Internal.css file for my internal page for a website. If I create a new page in DNN and apply this new skin it doesnt seem to apply the CSS. I copied the both ascx and css file to the _default/Skins/ folder.

Have also tried adding in the css via the following code

```
<dnn:DnnCssInclude runat="server" FilePath="/Internal.css" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" />
```

Nothing seems to be working. Have cleared my cache and tried different machine to view  the page. But the style is still not coming through.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder in the _default/Skins/. For example, call the folder "Internal" (/Portals/_default/Skins/Internal).  Copy your ascx and css skin files into there.  Rename the css to "skin.css".  You shouldn't need to reference it in the ascx since DNN will pick it up based on the name.

Also, the reason your CSS include statement may not have worked was because filepath "/Internal.css" was probably trying to look for it in the root of the website.  I would think it would simply be "Internal.css".  But you could verify in Firebug what path it generated.